# Watch OS tags - synonyms and completion

Tags: discussion, bug, tag-synonyms

I was looking at new tags and noticed these ones [watchos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watchos) and [watch](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watch). I thought there must be one already there and the main entry seems to be [apple-watch](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-watch) with synonyms including [watch-os](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watch-os).

This seems reasonable except for two issues

1. Shouldn't there be a difference tag for the hardware and the OS? I suspect this has been discussed so point me to where.
2. The main point of this post. If you create or edit an entry and start typing a tag watch  ... then  you get no completion and so we will get many new tags here i.e. the  [watchos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watchos) and [watch](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watch) Given the synonyms already here we want [watch-os](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watch-os) to show in the completions. Why does it not show. If we can't get this bug fixed and we have [watchos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watchos) added to the synonyms

Answer (score 4):

I agree and I think we should follow the same practice that we use for iPhone and iOS. Thus we should have at a high level [apple-watch](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-watch) for hardware and [watchos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watchos) for software. Also we should have break downs for watchOS so there should be [watchos-1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watchos-1) and [watchos-2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watchos-2), just like iOS. The only issue I see is that down-cased watchOS is a little hard to read.

Also I don't see why [workout.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/workout.app) is a synonym of [apple-watch](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-watch). That needs to be fixed too.

Comment: If watchOS ran on several platforms, then I'd think separate tags for hardware and software are in order, but since all Apple Watches run WatchOS and WatchOS only runs on Apple Watch, I don't see anything  gained by separate tags. We have too many tags already.

Comment: @Daniel I think it makes it much simpler to see what is a hardware issue and what is a software issue. Also why not be consistent and preemptive for when the next watch is release. It seems like it would be a big mess to untangle the tags after the fact. Also I think it is a good idea to follow StackOverflow's lead here which is to map tags to Wikipedia articles. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WatchOS

Comment: @Steve Moser Yeah, like you said if the ios tag and iphone tag are separate, I don't see why the watchos tag and the apple-watch tag shouldn't be separate, too.